# Using a static method in Model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Using EF6's Model Binding, can I refer to a static member of another class in the `SelectMethod` property? If yes, what's the syntax? A workaround would be to simply define a wrapper method in the code-behind that calls the foreign member, but I'm interested to see if the syntax directly supports it or not.

### Details

I can set `SelectMethod` of my `GridView` or `FormView` to a public member defined in the code-behind of the same page, just like:

```
<asp:GridView ... SelectMethod="MyMethod" ... />
```

where `MyMethod` is a public instance/static member defined in the code-behind of this very page. But if my method is a public static method defined in some other class, then `Class.MyMethod` syntax doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ObjectDataSource`

```
<asp:objectdatasource
       id="ObjectDataSource1"
       runat="server"
       selectmethod="MyMethod"
       typename="MyClass" />

<asp:gridview
       id="GridView1"
       runat="server"
       datasourceid="ObjectDataSource1" />
```

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/basic-reporting/displaying-data-with-the-objectdatasource-cs

Comment: Does it support static members defined in other classes (i.e. not in the code-behind of its own page)?

Comment: Yes, it does! Maybe you'll have to decorate the method with [DataObjectmethodAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataobjectmethodattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)